# How to use API with JavaScript and fetch function

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

My question is the following I have the code:

```
 const url = 'http://localhost:8080/users/[count]';
 fetch(url)
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {

for (i=o;i<data.length;i++) {
 document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = `<p>${data[i].name} ${data[i].username}</p>`
};
  

})
.catch(function(error) {
console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

That in theory should grab the information in address http: // localhost: 8080 / users / [count] and give me the values name and username found in this address.
The address has the following:

> [{"name":"Marisa Koss","username":"Adolfo.Klein","email":"Arnold29@hotmail.com","address":{"street":"Nils Mills","suite":"Apt. 415","city":"South Cortney","zipcode":"96235-6649","geo":{"lat":"-6.3807","lng":"-19.6170"}},"phone":"1-212-309-5985 x3453","website":"dovie.com","company":{"name":"Muller, Monahan and Stracke","catchPhrase":"Managed real-time matrices","bs":"rich maximize portals"}},{"name":"Ole Kulas","username":"Lesly.Walter","email":"Etha70@gmail.com","address":{"street":"White Isle","suite":"Suite 966","city":"Hermannland","zipcode":"13688","geo":{"lat":"-85.1722","lng":"133.7227"}},"phone":"1-161-247-6455 x898","website":"gina.name","company":{"name":"Rodriguez - Botsford","catchPhrase":"Extended leading edge ability","bs":"wireless evolve web-readiness"}},{"name":"Baylee Boehm","username":"Maximillia37","email":"Merl.Rath24@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Laisha Turnpike","suite":"Suite 277","city":"Cesartown","zipcode":"43786-5148","geo":{"lat":"3.6440","lng":"153.8556"}},"phone":"(027) 633-4660 x01161","website":"amari.org","company":{"name":"Wiegand and Sons","catchPhrase":"Advanced high-level open architecture","bs":"viral productize methodologies"}},{"name":"Chanelle Kub Jr.","username":"Mac.Stoltenberg10","email":"Willis_Gutkowski10@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Cecilia Harbor","suite":"Suite 605","city":"East Deonte","zipcode":"11840-8930","geo":{"lat":"-18.2002","lng":"105.6944"}},"phone":"071-752-1969 x96946","website":"tristin.info","company":{"name":"Corwin - Champlin","catchPhrase":"Balanced bi-directional collaboration","bs":"sticky embrace interfaces"}},{"name":"Vickie Wisozk","username":"Ladarius.Conroy98","email":"Lowell_Beer@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Cheyenne Village","suite":"Suite 849","city":"Farrellstad","zipcode":"67187","geo":{"lat":"4.3229","lng":"-125.2004"}},"phone":"1-247-291-1942 x5040","website":"doris.com","company":{"name":"Larson, Cormier and Stoltenberg","catchPhrase":"Profound discrete leverage","bs":"integrated benchmark ROI"}},{"name":"Laury Nader","username":"Eulalia62","email":"Lempi_Schimmel91@gmail.com","address":{"street":"Parker Junction","suite":"Apt. 389","city":"New Gabe","zipcode":"00367","geo":{"lat":"37.2142","lng":"79.3023"}},"phone":"(822) 093-1471 x9308","website":"junior.biz","company":{"name":"Hodkiewicz, Sporer and McClure","catchPhrase":"Inverse zero tolerance product","bs":"distributed generate solutions"}},{"name":"Laron Walker","username":"Rosalinda38","email":"Idella.Quigley72@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Rodriguez Knoll","suite":"Suite 488","city":"New Zakaryhaven","zipcode":"24722","geo":{"lat":"-0.9863","lng":"63.8521"}},"phone":"229-380-2044 x086","website":"jaden.biz","company":{"name":"Klein Group","catchPhrase":"Balanced foreground moderator","bs":"user-centric redefine e-markets"}},{"name":"Antonia Wilkinson","username":"Verdie.Casper","email":"Candelario.Mann@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Kuphal Harbor","suite":"Suite 661","city":"East Gregfurt","zipcode":"91590-9271","geo":{"lat":"-87.7308","lng":"25.9781"}},"phone":"307-166-2617","website":"marques.org","company":{"name":"Treutel LLC","catchPhrase":"Public-key discrete project","bs":"24/365 transform infomediaries"}},{"name":"Mr. Mateo Gottlieb","username":"Marina0","email":"Loyal.Weissnat49@gmail.com","address":{"street":"Connelly Throughway","suite":"Apt. 439","city":"Deionfort","zipcode":"49258","geo":{"lat":"-39.2334","lng":"177.2928"}},"phone":"763-148-7666 x4871","website":"roel.net","company":{"name":"Torp - Senger","catchPhrase":"Optional responsive complexity","bs":"viral strategize portals"}},{"name":"Hermann Wolff","username":"Mckayla.Anderson","email":"Guiseppe_Heidenreich@yahoo.com","address":{"street":"Justen Courts","suite":"Suite 217","city":"Lake Jovanburgh","zipcode":"52134-2599","geo":{"lat":"17.1201","lng":"106.4603"}},"phone":"650-449-3725 x0901","website":"heloise.net","company":{"name":"Marvin and Sons","catchPhrase":"Distributed didactic forecast","bs":"bleeding-edge reintermediate action-items"}}]

Could you tell me what my mistake is, or what should i do to get the data I need

When I check Dev Tools from chrome to see the error I get the following

Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/users/[count]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You have `for (i=o;i<data.length;i++) {`. Are you sure you didn't mean `for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {`? You can't 'add' to a character `o` ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: probably a CORS issue as that is exactly what the error is telling you ... and by the way, setting `no-cors` guarantees you will **NOT** have access to the response ... the only solution is to enable CORS on the server

Answer (score -2):

You have two options. Modify the server at http://localhost:8080 to allow cross origin requests by sending the following header to the user:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin>
```

The backend must also respond to HTTP OPTIONS requests (for POST requests). You can check the method, and if it's "OPTIONS", you can respond with just the CORS headers and an empty body.

Your other option is to use no-cors as an option when using fetch(). For example:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/[count]', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
});
```

For security reasons, you will not be able to read the response body and can only use methods GET, HEAD, or POST if you use no-cors.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header requires just the origin not the whole URL.

Comment: *"The backend must also respond to HTTP OPTIONS requests."* For simple GET requests, that's unnecessary.

Comment: *"you will not be able to read the response body"* OP clearly said that they want to fetch data.

Comment: Changes noted. Second solution may still be relevant.

Comment: Preflight requests might be send even for GET requests. It also depends on the headers.